# Undefined symbols GCC / C++ dynamically loadable *.so objects

Tags: c++, object, shared, dlopen

-I am trying to compile a netsnmp mib and extend the functionality of the snmp agent.

- When I try to start the daemon and load the shared object (*.so) , the daemon complains about undefined symbols. 
  "dlopen failed: Filename.so: undefined symbol: netsnmp_container_table_row_extract"
- On further prodding #nm -D -u Filename.so prints out a number of undefined references/ symbols
- Some of these references are  `system calls` specific to the snmp agent.
- I do not have any problem in compiling the code. All of the missing references/symbols are calls to the netsnmp agent.

Question :
1. How am I able to compile without resolving these symbols ? AFIK : These symbols must have been resolved statically. 
2. I assume the system is not able to resolve these at run time ? 
3. How could i get over this problem ? Any suggestions

Thanks 
S.S

Answer (score 1):

If the symbols are from another library, you should link against it at the compile time. If the symbols are from the main application, the application should be linked with `--export-dynamic`.